Enforce number of parameters of a function depending length of a given array
I want to implement the function below:
function myFunction(param) { ... }

And I want to add typing to this function so when it is called like below:
myFunction({ 
   args: ['arg1', 'arg2'],
   method: (param1: string, param2: string) => { }
})

I want typescript to enforce the number of parameters of the method  (param1: string, param2: string) => { } is the same as the number of items in the array ['arg1', 'arg2']

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

You can use const to force the same length of args and params:
Playground
function myFunction<const T extends any[]>
  (param: {
    args: T;
    method: (...args: NoInfer<T>) => void;
  }): void {
  // Implementation here
}

myFunction({
  args: ['arg1'],
  method: param1 => {}
})

myFunction({
  args: ['arg1', 'arg2'],
  method: (param1, param2) => {}
})

myFunction({
  args: ['arg1'],
  method: (param1, param2) => {} // too many args
})

myFunction({
  args: ['arg1'],
  method: (param1: number) => {} // wrong param type
})


It's working perfectly but I regret I simplified my question. For my real need, a have extra keys wrapping the object { args: ..., method: ... } like below:
myFunction({
customer: {
args: ['customerArg1', 'customerArg2'],
method: (param1: string, param2: string) => { }
},
vehicle: {
args: ['vehicleArg1'],
method: (param1: string) => { }
},
})
I performed some adjustements to handle this, but the resulting code does not allow me to have different lenght for arrays ['customerArg1', 'customerArg2'] and ['vehicleArg1']. Any suggestions ?

@Faly a guy asked exactly the same question even referring to yours, i've tried my best to answer but seems not so perfect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79309042/enforce-same-length-for-array-of-parameters-and-function-parameters

Thank you! your answer in the other post works perfectly. It's deleted, you should repost it I think

@Faly you can find a better solution in the question's comments

you can use TypeScript’s tuple types and generic constraints.
function myFunction<T extends string[], U extends (...args: T) => void>. 
 (param: {
     args: T;
     method: U;
 }): void {
  // Implementation here
 }

This applies TypeScript’s type inference and ensures that your method function always aligns with the args array’s structure.

but it doesn't ensure that.
