Enforce same length for array of parameters and function parameters
I want to implement an NgRx SignalStore feature, the syntax would be like:
withDetailFetching({ 
   contact: {
       argsFromRouterParams: ['contactId', 'tenantId'],
       method: (contactId: string, tenantId: string) => { }
   },
   userId: {
       argsFromRouterParams: ['userId'],
       method: (userId: string) => { }
   }
})

In this code, I want to enforce the typing so the number of parameters sent to contact.method (for example) is the same as the length of contact.argsFromRouterParams.
The typing I've already tried is below:
class WithDetailFetchingParam<T extends string[]> {
    argsFromRouterParams: T;
    method: () => (...args: NoInfer<T>) => any;
}

export function withDetailFetching<const P extends string[] >(param: { [key: string]: WithDetailFetchingParam<P>} ) {
// implementation
}

This typing works but it does not allow me to have different length for arrays contact.argsFromRouterParams and user.argsFromRouterParams:
Working:
withDetailFetching({ 
   contact: {
       argsFromRouterParams: ['contactId', 'tenantId'],
       method: (contactId: string, tenantId: string) => { }
   }
})

Not working:
withDetailFetching({ 
   contact: {
       argsFromRouterParams: ['contactId', 'tenantId'],
       method: (contactId: string, tenantId: string) => { }
   },
   userId: {
       argsFromRouterParams: ['userId'],
       method: (userId: string) => { }
   }
})

I've already found Enforce number of parameters of a function depending length of a given array, which helped me to do the typing above, but my need is little bit different.
How can I modify this implementation to allow for varying lengths of argsFromRouterParams while maintaining type safety between the parameters and the method?

Is the method type even correct there? I think what you want is something more like https://tsplay.dev/Wy7n6N.

Could the methods have spread arguments?

• Please [edit] this code to be a [mre]; your method typing seems to have an extra ()=> in it, confusing everything. • Once you fix that, it seems all you want is to use a mapped type as shown in this playground link. This gives you the behavior you're looking for, more or less, although TS has some assignability rules you might take issue with. Does it meet your needs or are there problems with it? (Please test thoroughly before replying). If it works I could write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, please [edit] to show unmet use cases.
